# Problems with a space character in my working directory in OSX High Sierra

Tags: python, macos, pip

I have recently updated my OSx installation to High Sierra. I did a fresh install and, when restoring from Time Machine, I had to create a new profile. The OS automatically created a new working directory with a space character in it. It was "cgh", became "cgh 1". Several applications had to be reinstalled and now I am having some problems with pip, notably with Flask in a virtual environment. If I try to install Flask in a new virtual environment, I get

(venv) iMac-2:itcmd cgh1$ pip install flask
-bash: /Users/cgh 1/itcmd/venv/bin/pip: "/Users/cgh: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

I have created an alias to the new working directory, but it does not work with Flask.

Any help with this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Spaces in directory names are evil.

Answer (score 2):

I do not have experience with Time Machine (I handle my own backups), but if there is a way to redo this restore and selecting a profile name without spaces that will save you a lot of suffering.

If you want a workaround, I think you can modify the first line in the `pip` script to make it work with a directory with spaces. Open `venv/bin/pip` in a text editor, and I guess you will see the path with spaces in line 1 (the shebang line). If you change it to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Then I think you'll be able to work with the virtualenv and install packages on it. You will obviously have to fix all venvs that you build, so I suggest you look into creating a new user with no spaces in the name.

Comment: I will try that. Thanks Miguel!

Comment: It worked! Thank you! I will be more careful in the next OSx upgrade and will not accept the default name suggested... Regards, Carlos

Comment: One more thing: I had to use the hack above on pip3 and pip3.6 files, too.